# storing integer in a int variable using NSXMLParser, in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, int, nsxmlparser

hii every one

i am doing a iphone project in that i need to take a int value from xml so
 how can i  store a integer value which is stored in a xml, into a int variable using NSXMLParser (by parsing the xml)

can any one give me some examples,,,   thanx in advance

Comment: Are you able use NSXMLParser to get the string for number ?

Comment: Show us a small example of the XML you are trying to parse and show us how far you have got so far.

Comment: <NumOfLables>5</NumOfLables> this is my xml  i did parsing also n stored that 5 in string after that i did type casting to int but that int variable contains some 5 digits number but not 5

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way (assuming you already know how to use NSXMLParser)

xml:

```
<intVariable>10</intVariable>
```

code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
    if(!currentElementValue)
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"intVariable"])
        intVariable = [currentElementValue intValue];

     [currentElementValue release];
     currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

(currentElementValue and intVariable are mutable string and int members respectively).

Comment: in currentElementValue value u r storing that value 10 and that currentElementValue is string,,but i need to store that in integer variable

Comment: Everything is interpreted as NSString with NSXMLParser. You use intValue to get the integer from the string. If you want to have other datatypes consider using JSON (SBJSON) instead of XML and you can get an NSNumber instead.